# Why the color of Sun is yellow, red or orange?

Tags: astrophysics, temperature, thermal-radiation, sun

Theoretically the maximum wavelength of sun radiation is approximately 500 nm. Then we should see the sun as green. But why do we see sun as yellow, orange or red?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the Sun appear green to our eyes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/171595/)

Comment: Unfortunately, that duplicate (which is indeed a duplicate) has three very lousy answers.

Comment: The answers there can appear lousy but once the solar spectrum (say out of the atmosphere for simplicity) the answer indeed resides in perception. Basically it is more related to how eyes and brain process the signal and the labels we have assigned to that. I would start digging in CIE colour space and things like that. There are  Daltonism and animals with grey vision, at the end. From a strictly physics side, just we known how solar spectrum is and how atmospheric optics work (abs, scatterings, ....).

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't comment yet, agree with Rob. Notice 1. lights with different angle in atmosphere, the sky turn different color in morning and before night. 2. atmosphere was a filter. 3. air molecular absorb and radiates.